# Neither filter nor filterM - Bool vs IO Bool difference

Tags: haskell, filter

I am trying to filter out those strings that contain a slash:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad(filterM)

hasSlash :: [Char] -> Bool
hasSlash firline = do
    isInfixOf "/" firline

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let d = ["abcd","abc/d","a/bcd","abcd","ab/cd"]
    -- filter out those that do not have '/'
    e <- filterM hasSlash d
    print e
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
soq_filter.hs:13:18: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘IO Bool’
      Expected type: [Char] -> IO Bool
        Actual type: [Char] -> Bool
    • In the first argument of ‘filterM’, namely ‘hasSlash’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: e <- filterM hasSlash d
      In the expression:
        do { let d = ...;
             e <- filterM hasSlash d;
             print e }
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks.

Comment: You might also like `hasSlash = elem '/'`.

Comment: You don't need `do`  in `hasSlash`; it doesn't do any monadic binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need or want `IO` or any other monad for that filtering. Do this instead:

```
import Data.List

hasSlash :: [Char] -> Bool
hasSlash firline = isInfixOf "/" firline

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let d = ["abcd","abc/d","a/bcd","abcd","ab/cd"]
    -- filter out those that do not have '/'
    let e = filter hasSlash d
    print e
```

Note the use of `let e =` instead of `e <-` to avoid needing a monadic context.

Comment: Good method. Thanks.